# Where does electrical power in PC or other electronic devices goes?

Tags: energy, electrons, computer

I am wondering where does energy goes for example in PC?

As I understand part of it definitely changes to the heat and dissipates, but what about rest of the energy? There is no moving parts except fan. Does the energy in PC is used to move electrons inside electrical components like CPU etc.

Thank you in advance :)

[Edit]
One more thought, some of the power can be dissipated in transistors because each transistor p-n junction have voltage drop of $0.7~\mathrm{V}$.

Comment: It all ends up as heat, dispersed every more uniformly throughout the computer and its surroundings as the Universe grinds inexorably onwards to its ultimate heat death ..... “Here I am, brain the size of a planet and they ask me to take you down to the bridge. Call that job satisfaction? ‘Cos I don’t.”

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Quoting Marvin the paranoid android? You might enjoy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VnbiVw_1FNs - especially the end.

Comment: @Floris I came up with the whole inexorable grinding towards the heat death bit and thought to myself, "that sounds exactly like something Marvin would say".

Comment: Quoting from memory: "Heat is work, and work's a curse/And all the heat in the universe/ is gonna cool down. /And there'll be no more heat. /And there'll be no more work. /And there'll be perfect peace. /Yeah! That's entropy, man!"

Answer (score 2):

> One more thought, some of the power can be dissipated in transistors because each transistor p-n junction have voltage drop of 0,7V.

Even in this case the power $ P = U \cdot I_b \approx 0.7 V \cdot I_b $ of the base current is dissipated into heat. Where else should it go?

Most transistors in PCs are MOS-Technology. So they don't need a current to operate. They're more like a capacitor. They get charged and discharged. The total amount is dissipated into heat in the resistance of the connections during the switch from low to high and vice versa. Of course a little bit of energy is converted into light, sound, movement etc. But still, the main amount is heat.